# Saltstack - win_path doesn't modify system PATH variable as expected

Tags: windows, devops, salt-stack

I've defined a following .sls state file:

```
npm:
  chocolatey.installed:
    - name: nodejs
    - version: 16.19.1

'C:\Program Files\nodejs':
  win_path.exists
```

After I apply state above, running `sudo salt 'minion_name' win_path.get_path` shows me that the path was added:

```
minion_name:
    - C:\Program Files\nodejs
    - %SystemRoot%\system32
    - %SystemRoot%
    - %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
    - %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
    - %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH
    - C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap
    - C:\Program Files\Salt Project\Salt
    - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
```

But when I run `sudo salt 'minion_name' cmd.run "echo %PATH%"` (or log into the Windows machine and run "echo %PATH%" there), the content of the variable is completely different:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Salt Project\Salt;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Am I missing something? Or is this a bug with `salt.modules.win_path`? Running `node --version` returns `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Also I'm sure that the path to nodejs executables is correct, I checked it after chocolatey installed the module.

Comment: You may need to reboot before system path changes take effect. At minimum you must restart any processes before they can see it.

Comment: Oh my god you were right, reboot did it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment changes are not picked up by running processes (including `cmd` shells and the `salt-minion` service) or their children.

To ensure a system variable change can be seen by everything, a reboot is required.